# INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY : Invalid cross reference id in After insert Trigger to create ContentDocumentLink

Tags: apex, trigger, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

I am encountering the following error when inserting a **ContentDocumentLink** record :

```
Error [statusCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, code=[xmlrpc=1202, statusCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, exceptionCode=INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, scope=PublicApi, http=400]
```

The insert operation is in an **After Insert** trigger on the object **ContentDocument**, I am trying to link the newly created ContentDocument with an existing Account. I already checked the following options :

- Checked that the Account Id in the LinkedEntityId fiel, and the ContentDocument Id in the ContentDocumentId field of ContentDocumentLink record are valid Salesforce Ids;
- The file is correctly uploaded and visible in Salesforce;
- I also tried with Ids in static strings of the existing Account and an already existing ContentDocument, and it didn't throw this error. I know that it is possible to create a ContentDocumentLink when a ContentDocument is inserted, since I already implemented it in another project but I no longer have access to the code.

Any tips on what I am missing would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

EDIT #1 : Trigger Handler code

```
List<ContentDocumentLink> doclinksToCreate = new List<ContentDocumentLink>();
   Map<String, String> docIdsToAccountIds = new Map<String, String>();
    Map<String, String> userIdsToDocIds = new Map<String, String>();
    for(ContentDocument oneDoc : docs){
        userIdsToDocIds.put(oneDoc.CreatedById, oneDoc.Id);
    }

    // Get a list of AccountIds related to portal users that created ContentDocuments
    List<User> portalUsers = [SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Profile.Name 
                            FROM User 
                            WHERE Id IN :userIdsToDocIds.keySet()
                            AND Profile.Name = :System.Label.TheProfileName];

    Set<String> accountIds = new Set<String>();
    for(User oneUser : portalUsers){
        docIdsToAccountIds.put(userIdsToDocIds.get(oneUser.Id), oneUser.AccountId);
    }

    for(String key : docIdsToAccountIds.keySet()){
        doclinksToCreate.add(new ContentDocumentLink(
            ContentDocumentId = key, //'0693M000000fhOcQAI'
            LinkedEntityId = docIdsToAccountIds.get(key), // '0013M000018llyNQAQ'
            ShareType = 'I',
            Visibility = 'AllUsers' 
        ));
    }

    Database.SaveResult[] results = Database.insert(doclinksToCreate, false);
    Database.SaveResult oneRes;
    List<String> accountsIdsToNotifyAbout = new List<String>();
    for(Integer i=0, size = results.size(); i<size; i++){
        oneRes = results[i];
        if(oneRes.isSuccess()){
            System.debug('Insert document link success for document with Id : '+doclinksToCreate[i].ContentDocumentId);
            accountsIdsToNotifyAbout.add(doclinksToCreate[i].LinkedEntityId);
        }else{
            System.debug('Error with document Id : '+doclinksToCreate[i].ContentDocumentId);
            for(Database.Error oneError : oneres.getErrors()){
                System.debug(oneError);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message, there is a message attribute which is missing.

Comment: does the running user have viz to the Account?

Comment: @Saroj Bera the message attribute doesn't add much details it says : "invalid cross reference id"

Comment: @cropredy the user doesn't have viz to the account, but it shouldn't be the cause because the trigger handler runs "without sharing" and the test I did with using an existing ContentDocument with a static Id worked without errors on the same Account.

Comment: @THEDJA - Please edit the Question and add some relevant code so it helps the community to find an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the logic behind the ContentDocumentLink creation in order to solve the problem. I wrote a trigger on after insert of a ContentVersion instead of a ContentDocument, then I query for the ContentDocumentId.

It had nothing to do with certain fields being null or access to apex classes and to objects.
I guess the issue comes from the ContentDocument record **not being committed** to the database yet in an after insert trigger ([Salesforce order of execution](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.238.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)) even if the **record Id** is available.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public Static void insertContentDocumentLink(String entityId , String contentdocumentid){
        ContentDocumentLink contentlink=new ContentDocumentLink();
        contentlink.LinkedEntityId=entityId;
        contentlink.contentdocumentid=contentdocumentid;//[select contentdocumentid from contentversion where id =: objVersion.id].contentdocumentid;
        contentlink.ShareType = 'I';
        contentlink.Visibility = 'AllUsers'; 
        insert contentlink;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. This answer could be improved by adding some explanation and describing  how this code helps in resolving the question.

Comment: Thank you but that didn't help solve the problem.

Comment: can you share your trigger code on ContentDocument

Comment: I updated the post with the trigger handler code

Comment: SELECT Id, AccountId, Account.Name, Profile.Name 
                            FROM User 
                            WHERE Id IN :userIdsToDocIds.keySet()
                            AND Profile.Name = :System.Label.TheProfileName
can you add **AccountId!=NULL**?
can you check any triggers on Content Document Link ?

Seems it's only for community users right? can you check respected classes, and object permission to that user?

Comment: I already checked the access to the classes and also that the AccountId is not null, so that's not the root cause.